# Only print opening in Groovy MarkupBuilder

Tags: html, groovy, markupbuilder

I have code like the following

```
public String printHeader(){
    println "<html><head>...</head><body><table>"
}

public String doMiddleStuff(blahblah){
    println <tr><td>etcetc</td></tr>
}

public String printFooter(){
    println "</table></body></html>"
}
```

I want to use Groovy's MarkupBuilder, but when you do

```
new MarkupBuilder(writer).html{
...
}
```

It both opens and closes my tags. Is there a way I can split this stuff up, while still taking advantage of MarkupBuilder?

Comment: It seems unclear to me. Could provide working code and show what's not working exactly?

Comment: i think he wants to use the markup-builder to build just the opening/closing tags and do random stuff in between.  i don't think, that MarkupBuilder is intended to work in such a way and therefor will not easily bend to make it work.

Comment: Thanks cfrick, that's exactly what I'd wanted to know.